# VS Code integrated terminal not starting with virtual environment activated while the right interpreter is being selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

**Platform and software versions:**

> Mac OS Mojave, VS Code 1.38.0, Python extension installed. Created
>   virtual environment in project directory using command 
>   `python3 -m env`. 
>   Modified setting in Python extension, 
>   `"python.venvPath": "bin",` to handle the bin directory where the python for the virtual
>   environment is stored.

**Situation:**

When I launch VS Code using `code .`, and then open a python file in the folder, the interpreter selected is ./bin/python, however the integrated terminal is not set to the right python executable. If I launch a new terminal it sources the virtual environment (which may be due to the Python extension setting `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`)

**Question:**

Is there a way to have the integrated terminal also have the virtual environment sourced?

Or is there a better way to have VS Code activate virtual environment created by `python3 -m env .`?

Thank you.

---

Edit:

Just reread the VS Code documentation here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments and this time noticed this below. Wondering if there is a way to kill the existing terminal and then launch one upon VS Code launch...

> However, launching VS Code from a shell in which a certain Python environment is activated does not automatically activate that environment in the default integrated terminal. Use the Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal command after VS Code is running.

Answer (score 2):

Two things. One, `"python.venvPath"` is meant to point at a directory that contains other virtual environments, not the `bin/` directory that has a Python interpreter from a virtual environment. (I also don't know what `python3 -m env` is supposed to do; did you mean `python3 -m venv`?)

Two, there isn't a way to make VS Code automatically launch and complete the loading of the Python extension before VS Code creates a terminal if you have the terminal frame open at start-up.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writting vscode now has

```py
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

so I my *global* `settings.json`, <kbd>F1</kbd> > *preference: Open Settings (JSON)*

```py
"python.venvPath": "D:/miniconda3/envs",
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

and in my workspace's `settings.json`, <kbd>F1</kbd> > *preference: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)*

```py
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "D:/miniconda3/envs/my-workspace-venv/python.exe"
```

And it works for me.